# rails s not working with my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

Hey guys I have been working on a rails app, and the rails server was working. Then I added more code, and all the sudden the rails server is not working now. I keep getting this message:

```
Usage:


rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog
```

My app is called bloccit, and in my terminal shell I am in my code/bloccit directory but still nothing. If anyone could help with any tips I would be very thankful!

Comment: @Vishal, why are you asking for the output of `rails -v` since he is not asking how to get the version of `rails`? Instead, he is asking why his `rails s` is not working.

Comment: Are you sure that is the solution? It's not.

Comment: It's not the solution but additional information that could possibly lead to it.

Comment: So, you are in a wrong path to investigate his problem.

Comment: Are you developing locally or using a cloud based editor?

Comment: I'm developing locally

Comment: @vishal my rails -v  is  Rails 4.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rails s` runs scripts located in your app's `bin` directory. Without it, you get the message shown above.

I asked for the contents of your app directory (using `ls`) and you responded:

```
Gemfile Rakefile config.ru log tmp Gemfile.lock 
app db public vendor README.md config lib spec
```

As you can see, your `bin` directory is missing. It must be restored/replaced.

If you moved it or threw it in the trash, restore it.

If you deleted it, you can copy one from another/new Rails app. Create a folder somewhere outside your existing app, generate an empty Rails app (`rails new throwaway`), then go in and copy the `bin` folder to your existing app.

Comment: Thank you soooo much man!  I was like what the heck happened! My bin file got moved into my views folder I moved it out and it worked again!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are in your root application directory. That error you posted is commonly seen if you are not in root application directory.

You can use `pwd` command to show where is your current directory. You said that your app name is `bloccit` and you should be in that root directory and fire `rails s`.

Comment: Ya thank you  I ran the server probably 5 mins before, then exited out, to add more  but now it will not run the server. I didn't change branches or directories or anything. Plus I have run pdw and it says `/Users/ethanfranson/Code/bloccit` so is there anything else you can think of?

Comment: Run `ls` and post the output.

Comment: My ls came out with : `Gemfile  Rakefile config.ru log  tmp
Gemfile.lock app  db  public  vendor
README.md config  lib  spec`

Comment: You are missing `bin` scripts. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that it's suggesting you to create a new rails app because it's unable to identify your Rails app.
Since you're using Rails version 4.x, it looks for bin/rails to identify a Rails app. If you don't have bin directory at the root of your application, try to run `rake rails:update:bin`

Comment: I wanted to say thank you! my bin file was moved, on accident. So thanks a lot for all your help!